# What does the cache bank mean in AMD CPU?

Tags: caching, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache, amd-processor

In AMD's optimization manual, the L1 Data cache is described as follows:

> **The L1 DC provides multiple access ports using a banked structure.** The read ports are shared by three load pipes and victim reads. Store commits utilize separate write ports. Which DC banks are accessed is determined by address bits 5:3 by the access, the size of the access, and the DC way. DC way is determined using the linear-address-based utag/way-predictor

What does the bank here mean in terms of hardware? What is the relationship between it and the logical set/way of cache?

Is the bank designed similarly to [memory bank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_bank)?

Comment: Probably similar to Sandybridge, where e.g. the first 16 bytes of each cache line were in one bank, etc.  Simultaneous access to different lines of the same bank were a problem.  I think this is an alternative to truly multi-ported cache like Haswell and later used to make cache-bank conflicts not a thing anymore.  Agner Fog explains this better, see his microarch guide (https://agner.org/optimize/).